# jquery mobile scroll up after lod page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a problem with jquery mobile and panel, I use a simple panel but if I have a long image and I scroll downa before the page is loaded when it finish to load the page scroll up, if I remove the link to jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js the page don't scroll up.

Comment: Without the code or a some sort of example, there is no way to help. Please provide a code example of what you're doing in jsfiddle or in the post.

Comment: I add a link to website

Comment: I am still unable to replicate the issue as you described it, nor does looking at this website help explain what the issue is or what code is being used. What is it exactly that is happening, what are you expecting, and how do you need help?

Comment: today I work and I study jquery mobile code and I discorver the problem, commenting some piece of code I solve it!